# Empty log for Safari Push Notifications webservice

Tags: safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, safari-push-notifications

I've implemented Safari Push Notifications both server-side and client-side. On the client, after asking for permissions, the callback function is called with permission "denied".

On the server-side, the logs show that a request for the push package has been made and returns a 200, but a few seconds later the /v1/log endpoint is called with no payload.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful tip is to look in the System Log, from the Console app. Safari shows messages in there.

Another reason for my issue is realted to Django, which as 1.5 doesn't show non-form data in `request.POST`, but in `request.body`.

Answer (score 0):

May help following guide and push package creator.

[browser-push](https://lahiiru.github.io/browser-push/)

Comment: This is heavily outdated as it still references v1 endpoints.